# React & Axios ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: reactjs, axios, client-certificates

I'm having an issue making an https request with [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) using certificates within React (via [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)). Basically, my requests are returning `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

The relevant code:

```
const agent = new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  ca: process.env.REACT_APP_CA_CERT,
  cert: process.env.REACT_APP_CERT,
  key: process.env.REACT_APP_KEY
});

const instance = axios.create({
  httpsAgent: agent
});

const response = await instance.get(myURL);
```

Here's the thing... if I create a simple Node script with the above code and run it from my machine, it works just fine. It's only in React and within my browser (Chrome) that I'm seeing an error.

Is there some additional setting I need for Axios?

Comment: can you give us a screenshot or the text of the error message? Also could you show us  how you are using it in react?

Comment: How I'm calling it in React is basically the code above. In Chrome's console, I basically see: `GET https://<myUrl> net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

Comment: I *think* I figured out the root of my issue. The `https` module is not available in the client/browser environment, only in the Node environment. So the only way I can make a request that requires a certificate is to run a local Node server and proxy my React requests through it (I already had a setup that does this, but I was hoping I wouldn't need such a proxy server)